# Angular doesn't work despite copy and pasting

Tags: angularjs

I have spend hours on angular tutorial and I cannot even get the basics of Angular to work for very long now.

I copy and paste the entire code from here:
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_default

onto my sublime editor and run it.
It still doesn't work. There is no error message at all.

The html works but the angular expression doesn't appear at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="">

<p>Input something in the input box:</p>
<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter name here"></p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

<-----------------------------PYTHON BELOW----------------------------------->

```
from flask import Flask , render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/index")
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: See your browser console log for any errors.

Comment: Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated.  Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead. requestNotifier.js:64
Error: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: Updated the script src to the latest angular version. Now the console doesn't show a single error log.

Comment: I've just pasted your code into an html file then opened it in the browser, it works just fine. You must do something else. How do you test it exactly?

Comment: I used it with a simple python flask server.

Comment: Are you familiar with the console?  Does your sever maybe not allow getting js from another server?  Can you serve angular from your server?  What's the value of 'angular' in the console?  The **newest** version of angular might not be compatible.  Check your network tab in your browser console too.

Comment: ... For one, ng-app cannot be empty. You also need a controller to bind your template.

Comment: @KGChristensen yes, ng-app can be empty. And no, you don't need a controller. http://plnkr.co/edit/iF1kFioY29vapFpYkTq6?p=preview

Comment: The problem seems to be with the flask. If I just run the html file by itself. There is no problem executing angular. But if I run it with the python flask server. The angular expression {{ }} doesn't work.

Comment: I Have solved the problem. With flask.ext.triangle .